# Modify list in Python

Tags: python

my code is :

```
>>> lis=['ALRAGUL','AKAL','to7a']
>>> for i in lis:
  if i.startswith('AL'): 
    j=lis[lis.index(i)+1] 
    L=list(itertools.repeat(j, 2)) 
    lis[lis.index(i)+1]=L
    lis[lis.index(i)+1]=i[2: ] 
    lis[lis.index(i)]='AL'
>>> print lis
['AL', 'RAGUL', 'to7a']
```

But I want the result to become :

```
['AL', 'RAGUL','AKAL' 'to7a']
```

and I want it somehow general meaning that the code works with whatever words are and with whatever arrangement of them is 
For example I want it to split ('AL') under any conditions 
thx alot :)

Comment: What is the logic behind this code? What is it even doing?

Comment: To clarify, it should only split if `AL` is at the beginning of a string? Because `AKAL` isn't split in your example.

Comment: @ thegrinner yes I wanted it only at the beginning..thx, that is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Why has this question been aggressively down voted? This seems a legit topic, the OP tried to show what he had done so far, and it is not obvious on its face how to do this. Let's not make SO a mean place...

Comment: @drewk dunn care about voting ..I dunn care .Let people think what they think about you

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
def separate(lst, chunk):
    for n in lst:
        if n.startswith(chunk):
            for x in n.partition(chunk)[1:]:
                yield x
        else:
            yield n
```

And the output:

```
In [104]: list(separate(['ALRAGUL','AKAL','to7a'], 'AL'))
Out[104]: ['AL', 'RAGUL', 'AKAL', 'to7a']
```

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do it:

```
>>> lis = ['ALRAGUL', 'AKAL', 'to7a']
>>> for i, s in list(enumerate(lis)):
...   if s.startswith('AL'):
...     lis[i:i+1] = ['AL', s[2:]]
... 
>>> lis
['AL', 'RAGUL', 'AKAL', 'to7a']
>>>
```

Comment: what about if I want to add another condition , something like that :
>>> lis = ['ALRAGUL', 'AKALH', 'to7a']
>>> for i, s in list(enumerate(lis)):
 if s.startswith('AL'):
  lis[i:i+1] = ['AL',s[2:]]
 if s.endswith('H'):
  lis[i:i+1] = [s[:-1],'H']

  
>>> lis
['AL', 'AKAL', 'H', 'AKALH', 'to7a']

But I want the result to be :
['AL','RAGUL','AKAL','H','to7a']

any ideas ?
Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
from itertools import chain
import re

print filter(None, chain.from_iterable(re.split('^(AL)', el) for el in lis))
```

Or:

```
filter(None, chain.from_iterable(map(re.compile ('^(AL)').split, lis)))
```