# Modify list in Python

Tags: python

my code is :

```
>>> lis = ['ALRAGUL', 'AKALH', 'to7a']
>>> for i, s in list(enumerate(lis)):   
        if s.startswith('AL'):      
            lis[i:i+1] = ['AL',s[2:]]   
        if s.endswith('H'):             
            lis[i:i+1] =[s[:-1],'H']
>>> lis     
['AL', 'AKAL', 'H', 'AKALH', 'to7a']
```

But I want the result to become :

```
['AL', 'RAGUL', 'AKAL', 'H', 'to7a']
```

and I want it somehow general meaning that the code works with whatever words are and with whatever arrangement of them is. For example I want it to split (`'AL'`) whenever it comes at the beginning and I want to split (`'H'`) whenever it comes at the end under any conditions thx alot :)

Comment: And you tagged this question as `c#` for...?

Comment: I've tried to fix your indentation, but please look it over and make sure this is what your code actually looks like.

Comment: How will you split `'ALRAGULH'`?

Comment: Side note: There is no reason to do `for i, s in list(WHATEVER)`, because `for i, s in WHATEVER` will do the exact same thing (except in certain rare cases, like where `WHATEVER` is an iterator being consumed by other code at the same time).

Comment: Well, you've undone my indentation fix, and also removed the part about what happens when you run it. Does this mean I guessed wrong, and what actually happens when you run it is an immediate `IndentationError`?

Comment: You asked [this exact question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287613/modify-list-in-python) two days ago, and it was closed. Why are you expecting different results now?

Comment: what I want is to split ['AL'] whenever it comes at the begening and split ['H'] whenever it comes at the end

Comment: @Cairnarvon coz I needed to add another condition and I don't know how to do it

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary ['AL','RAGUL,'H']

Comment: @abarnert yes that's what I meant..I just dunn know how to mark a code when I ask a question

Comment: What about ALALyuH should this be AL, AL, yu, H or Al, ALuy, H ?

Comment: @MuhammedKK No splitting of 'AL' only happen at the  beginning and for 'H' only at the end

Comment: @user1996764 Then my script seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this using a generator function:

```
lis = ['ALRAGUL','AKALH', "AL", 'H','ALH' ,'to7a','ALRAGULH']

def solve(lis):
    for x in lis:
        if x.startswith("AL") and x.endswith("H"):
            yield x[:2]
            if len(x)>4:
                yield x[2:-1]
            yield x[-1]
        elif x.startswith("AL"):
            yield x[:2]
            if len(x)>2:
                yield x[2:]
        elif x.endswith("H"):
            if len(x)>1:
                yield x[:-1]
            yield x[-1]
        else:
            yield x

new_lis = list(solve(lis))
print new_lis
```

**output:**

```
['AL', 'RAGUL', 'AKAL', 'H', 'AL', 'H', 'AL', 'H', 'to7a', 'AL', 'RAGUL', 'H']
```

Comment: can I insert the result in a variable to use it ??

Comment: @user1996764 yes, just store the returned value in a variable. see my updated answer.

Comment: @user1996764 you need to click on the tick mark on the left side of my answer in order to accept it.

Comment: @user1996764 accepting the answer is the only way you can thank us. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a new list instead. This will prevent you from having index issues which you have (because `i` does not update when you insert another item in between of the list):

```
>>> lis = ['ALRAGUL', 'AKALH', 'to7a']
>>> lisNew = []
>>> for s in lis:
        if s != 'AL' and s.startswith('AL'):
            lisNew.append('AL')
            s = s[2:]
        if s != 'H' and s.endswith('H'):
            lisNew.append(s[:-1])
            lisNew.append('H')
        else:
            lisNew.append(s)
>>> lisNew
['AL', 'RAGUL', 'AKAL', 'H', 'to7a']
```

Comment: Still doesn't works for strings like `"AL"` ,`"H"` or `"ALH"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
lis = ['ALRAGUL', 'ALRAGUL', 'AKALH', 'to7a', 'ALRAGULH', 'AL', 'H', 'ALH']
i = 0
for s in list(lis):
    i = lis.index(s, i)
    if s.startswith('AL') and len(s) > 2:
        lis[i:i + 1] = ['AL', s[2:]]
        s = s[2:]
        i += 1

    if s.endswith('H') and len(s) > 1:
        lis[i:i + 1] = [s[:-1], 'H']
        i += 1

print lis # ['AL', 'RAGUL', 'AL', 'RAGUL', 'AKAL', 'H', 'to7a', 'AL', 'RAGUL', 'H', 'AL', 'H', 'AL', 'H']
```

Comment: yes it does work..Thx a lot :)
and I am really sorry if I disturbed any one here

Comment: This won't work if there are any repeated strings in the list. The `i = list.index(s)` will find the first index of a string matching `s`, even if you're looking at the second string.

Comment: @user1996764 this doesn't works if the string is "AL" or "H".

Comment: ya..it gives me this error :
File "<pyshell#114>", line 3
    if s.startswith('AL'):
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Code updated. I guess this will work with all the conditions.

Comment: this time you did it :D
Good job Muhammed :)